# Can imported library functions get moved in memory

Tags: c++, winapi

Assuming that a library is not unloaded and reloaded, will a function address pointing to a function in a library stay the same for whole execution time?

```
HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary("SomeLibrary.dll");
SomeFunction fn = (SomeFunction)GetProcAddress(hm, "SomeFunction");
fn(arg1, arg2); // is fn valid for whole execution time?
```

Comment: I mean, it's a pointer ? It's pointing to an area in your memory, as long as it's not unloaded it should stay the same as it won't be claimed by another pointer.

Comment: That's what i thought, but what i did not know for sure is whether there is some os functionality that moves memory around for whatever reason. Thanks

Comment: if function address can be suddenly moved ( fn can become invalid at any time) - use it impossible at all. in this case `GetProcAddress` full lost sense.

Comment: The function address *can* change in physical memory, but its virtual address will stay the same throughout the lifetime of a function. The OS handles the mapping between virtual addresses and physical addresses transparently for you.

Comment: Good info. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming that a library is not unloaded and reloaded, will a function address pointing to a function in a library stay the same for whole execution time?

Yes.